# In a Banach space, absolute convergence of series implies convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

**Proof/Hint Request :**

I came upon a shortly stated Lemma while revising for my Functional Analysis semester exam. It follows as :

**Lemma :** The absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty}x_n$ implies the converge of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} x_n$, where $x_n$ is a sequence in a Banach Space.

Now, I know that the absolute convergence of the noted sequence means that $\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \|x_n\|$ is convergent, but I cannot see how to find a way to prove the lemma.

Any hints or elaborations will be appreciated.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes, I apologise, forgot to mention. Added now.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999121/if-sum-n-1-infty-x-n-lt-infty-then-lim-k-to-infty-sum-n-1k-x?rq=1) is related, almost a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**  Use the triangle inequality:   $\mid S_n-S_m\mid=\mid x_n+x_{n-1}+\dots +x_{m+1}\mid\le \mid x_n\mid+\dots+\mid x_{m+1}\mid$.

Then $S_n$ will be Cauchy, hence convergent.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is incorrect in general - you need to be working over a Banach space. As for a hint when this is true:

Suppose $(x_n)$ is absolutely summable and consider the difference
$$ |a_n-a_m|,$$
where $a_k = \sum_{j=0}^k x_j$. Using absolute summability can you show that $a_n$ is Cauchy?

Edit: thinking about it, the property of absolute convergence implying convergence (for sums) should be equivalent to the Banach property. As a challenge maybe try to prove the opposite implication than the one in this question.

Comment: Folland's Measure Theory and Functional Analysis text proves this converse, and then I think uses it to prove the quotient of a Banach space by a closed subspace is again Banach.  (I also remember this condition being convenient in proving the space of signed measures on a $\sigma$-algebra, with norm being total variation $\lVert \mu \rVert = |\mu|(X)$, is a Banach space.)